# Making a 500C electric oven?

Tags: oven

A lot of nice breads and food are meant to be cooked for a few minutes in fired ovens around 400-500C. This tends to give the bread the great crust you simply cannot get at lower temperatures. Typical home ovens struggle to get up to 275C, so I am interested in finding a higher temperature solution.

Since electricity is the cleanest way to produce heat, I would expect to find (reasonably) affordable electric ovens that get up to 500C, but I don't. I see $1500 massive Italian ovens (taking up a huge 6-12kW in power...) and $400 gas ovens. But I don't see a reasonably affordable electric oven that gets up 500C. This is surprising to me.

Does anyone have suggestions for making a 500C electric oven and the associated challenges?

Some desirable specifications

1. Works outside
2. Can have a small volume (ie for flatbreads, pizza, and kebobs, not turkeys)
3. Ideally works from standard North American wall outlet(s). Could be multiple outlets if needed
4. Gets up to between 450C and 500C approximately

Comment: you can only get about 2kw from a "standard North American wall outlet"; nowhere near enough for a practical/affordable oven that could cook bread.

Comment: There's plenty of ovens with pyrolytic cleaning on the market, and "pyrolytic cleaning" stands for "heat up to 500°C and wait for all the gunk to burn up". You could conceivably abuse that feature for your purposes (just make sure you don't get an oven which locks the door for hours when you engage the cleaning cycle), but doing that will likely void the warranty.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can actually cook bread properly at 500C. Looking at oven temperatures on Wikipedia, I found an article about cooking [Verace Pizza Napoletana](https://www.pizzanapoletana.org/public/pdf/disciplinare%202008%20UK.pdf) @ 485C, and it takes only 60-90 seconds to cook, but it is a pizza. I can't imagine a loaf of bread properly rise in 60 seconds and not burn on the outside while being raw on the inside.

Comment: @Nelson, I had mostly flatbread (pizza, naan) in mind which cook really fast at these high temps and have amazing texture. Yes,  ordinary sandwich bread loaves would just burn

Comment: @TooTea, very interesting. Do you know of any small "toaster oven" type machines with the high temperature pyrolitic cleaning option?

Comment: You won't find self cleaning small (countertop) ovens for a bunch of reasons.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of electric ovens that can heat to 500C.   They are marketed as "kilns".  Buy one.  Done.

[image]

Seriously, kilns are not sold as ovens mainly because there's not much of a market for 500C electric domestic ovens.  There is a growing market for outdoor pizza ovens but those are much much easier and cheaper to install with gas or more authentic if they use wood or coal so that's how they're sold.  But a kiln is an oven, so don't get distracted by marketing.

How to make a kiln from scratch is not a question for this forum but you'll find lots of youtube videos in the "bushcraft" genre of resourceful barefoot types doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Oh man, now I want Mod Pizza...